# Alterar a cor da toolbar no primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Queria mudar a cor de fundo do toolbar qual seria a tag

```
<p:toolbar>
    <f:facet name="right">
        <h:commandButton value="Sair" style="color: "/>
    </f:facet>
</p:toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao acessar a sua página através do navegador, vai em inspecionar elemento, clica em cima do objeto que você quer saber as informações e procure a tag class, no caso de toolbar do primefaces tem as informações de todos os elementos que compõem o objeto.

```
class="ui-toolbar ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"
```

No seu css você declara a classe

```
.ui-toolbar {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Nesse caso todas as vezes que você chamar o toolbar virá essas informações, caso você queira essa aplicação de cor somente em uma tag, o certo seria você criar um styleClass.

```
<p:toolbar styleClass="teste">
    <f:facet name="right">
        <h:commandButton value="Sair" style="color: "/>
    </f:facet>
</p:toolbar>
```

..

```
.teste {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: Sim tinha feito dessa forma, porem ele pega a cor e depois some. como se outra configuração do css estivesse atrapalhando existe alguma tag que obrigue ele a utilizar apenas esse css com a cor que eu escolhi ?

Comment: Tenta colocar !important na frente da configuração: background-color: red !important;

Comment: Por ele pegar a cor e depois sumir, faz uns teste em outra página e na página atual verifica também se não tem outro toobar no arquivo, talvez um esteja sobrepondo o outro, e isso pode ser alguma configuração no css.